# Error occuring in my Java/Android code on import line

Tags: java, android

I am really new to Android Studio, and am trying to get up to speed. I got some code from the web and I have an errors I know it is because I am referencing a package that is not in my project but how could I resolve this.

The line that has the error is:

> import com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity;

and this is the full code.

```
package org.quaestio.kotlinconvertedwebview;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity;

import java.util.Random;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

Thread splashTread;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.s_img,R.drawable.s_image_black, R.drawable.s_image_black2};
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int r= randomGenerator.nextInt(ids.length);
    this.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ids[r]));

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 3500) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `import com.androidmkab.randomsplash.MainActivity` means where the MainActivity is located, you need to replace that package with your own. To do this copy your package name(in the top of your activity) and add the activity you want to import, in this case MainActivity.java: `import org.quaestio.kotlinconvertedwebview.MainActivity;`

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes that was it